# Refering to subclasses in the superclass (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors, subclass, superclass

I've got a problem with the implementation of my design. There is a superclass defining methods, which have subclasses of this superclass as return values. As you can see here:

```
#ifndef I_ATTITUDEDESCRIPTOR_H
#define I_ATTITUDEDESCRIPTOR_H

#include "cl_EulerAngles.h"
#include "cl_Quaternion.h"
#include "cl_RodriguesParameters.h"
#include "cl_RotationMatrix.h"
#include "cl_TransformationMatrix.h"

class i_AttitudeDescriptor {
    public:
        i_AttitudeDescriptor();
        virtual ~i_AttitudeDescriptor() = 0;

        virtual cl_EulerAngles* getEulerAngles(cl_EulerAngles* result) = 0;
        virtual cl_Quaternion* getQuaternion(cl_Quaternion* result) = 0;
        virtual cl_RodriguesParameters* getRodriguesParameters(cl_RodriguesParameters* result) = 0;
        virtual cl_RotationMatrix* getRotationMatrix(cl_RotationMatrix* result) = 0;
        virtual cl_TransformationMatrix* getTransformationMatrix(cl_TransformationMatrix* result) = 0;
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // I_ATTITUDEDESCRIPTOR_H
```

One of the subclasses is for example given by:

```
#ifndef CL_EULERANGLES_H
#define CL_EULERANGLES_H

#include "i_AttitudeDescriptor.h"

#include "cl_Quaternion.h"
#include "cl_RodriguesParameters.h"
#include "cl_RotationMatrix.h"
#include "cl_TransformationMatrix.h"


class cl_EulerAngles : public i_AttitudeDescriptor
{
    public:
        cl_EulerAngles();
        ~cl_EulerAngles();

        cl_EulerAngles* getEulerAngles(cl_EulerAngles* result);
        cl_Quaternion* getQuaternion(cl_Quaternion* result);
        cl_RodriguesParameters* getRodriguesParameters(cl_RodriguesParameters* result);
        cl_RotationMatrix* getRotationMatrix(cl_RotationMatrix* result);
        cl_TransformationMatrix* getTransformationMatrix(cl_TransformationMatrix* result);
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // CL_EULERANGLES_H
```

The functions are implemented in the cl_EulerAngles.cpp file. Now I got the problem, that I get a compiler error like this:

```
i_AttitudeDescriptor.h|17|error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'|
i_AttitudeDescriptor.h|17|error C2433: 'i_AttitudeDescriptor::cl_EulerAngles': 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations|
i_AttitudeDescriptor.h|17|error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed|
i_AttitudeDescriptor.h|17|error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cl_EulerAngles'|
i_AttitudeDescriptor.h|17|error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed|
i_AttitudeDescriptor.h|17|warning C4183: 'getEulerAngles': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'|
i_AttitudeDescriptor.h|17|error C2253: "i_AttitudeDescriptor::getEulerAngles": pure specifier only applies to virtual function – specifier ignored|
||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 1 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

I'm hoping someone out there can help me fixing this little problem.
Thank you.

Comment: The base class really shouldn't know about any derived classes. Consider returning base class pointers and using polymorphism.

Comment: You have a problem with the design itself. The base class shouldn't return instances of derived classes. You could use forward declarations to solve the issue, but it won't fix the design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compilation problem is because of the circular include directives. However, underneath the simple circular inclusion, there is a bigger design problem here. Base class is not supposed to know the subclasses.

**Better solution:** You should return a pointer to the Base class and use [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

**Not that good solution:** If you really want to continue with your current design, you might consider not including the subclass headers, but forward declaring your subclasses in the base class header file. This will solve the circular inclusion.

I would recommend sticking with the first solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is circular includes; `i_AttitudeDescriptor.h` pulls in `cl_EulerAngles.h`, which pulls in `i_AttitudeDescriptor.h`. Once the include guards kick in, you end up missing declarations, which seems to be what the compiler is complaining about.

There are at least two solutions:

1. Forward declare the various types that are used in `i_AttitudeDescriptor.h` instead of `#include`ing their header files. `i_AttitudeDescriptor` doesn't care about the details of those classes, just their names.
2. Declare all those virtual functions in `i_AttitudeDescriptor` as returning pointers to `i_AttitudeDescriptor` rather than pointers to the specific types. You can still override them in derived classes with functions that return pointers to the derived types.